# How to jump to a specific section of a page after location.reload() in js?

Tags: javascript, html, window, reload

I am reloading a specfic page . But after reloading it is jumping to the top of the page which i dont want . Is there any other way where i can jump to a specific section so that it scrolls by itself to that section after reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Js has a function `document.location.reload()` which stores the position. You can add an additional `true` parameter to force reload, but without restoring the position.

```
document.location.reload(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `location.href` with address hook instead of `location.reload`

Like this:

```js
window.location.href = window.location.href+'#my_hoock';
```

```html
First content</br>
First content</br>
First content</br>
First content</br>

<div id="my_hoock">Div for show after reload</div>

Second content</br>
Second content</br>
Second content</br>
Second content</br>
```